# How is this question historically significant?

Tags: discussion

https://serverfault.com/questions/649171/damage-control-stolen-laptop

This question was downvoted and closed, but I would like to know: How is it significant?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has a historical lock because a former moderator placed the lock there. I don't know why he did it. I can't even begin to speculate. But removing the lock would change little: The question is terrible and the user isn't going to fix it.

There's probably still room for a *good* question along these lines, but this wasn't it. No longer seen in this post are several deleted comments where the poster explicitly stated it was a "test" question and people reacted quite negatively to that. Then he claimed it was based on a real situation, but refused to clarify it so that he could get a proper answer.

I'm pretty sure we'd lose just about nothing if the question were deleted. If anyone else has seen it since the week it was posted, I'd be surprised.

Comment: Delete away, for my money.  I note that locked questions can't be delete-voted, either; if you don't want to delete it you might consider removing the lock so the community can express itself in the normal way.

Comment: IIRC mod edits to locked questions don't get bumped to the front page. A historical lock is easy to apply. I suspect that this would have all been cleaned up except that the events that cause the mod to be come ex interrupted the activity.I'm with @madhatter and would cast s delete vote if I were able.

Comment: Yet another reason we should all be grateful to The Powers That Be for unilaterally nuking an elected mod.

Comment: I've removed the lock so the community can express itself in the normal way.

Comment: @MichaelHampton now it's deleted, but I wonder if Chris loose some points as is answer was good (with a +4), as usually the OP can't delete is own question if an usefull answer was gave.

Comment: @yagmoth555 After a post gets old enough, the reputation doesn't go away if the post is deleted. I don't recall the exact time offhand though.

Comment: @MichaelHampton ah, thanks for the input :) didnt knew that

Comment: @MichaelHampton Do you happen to have a source for that information? I thought it was based on the impact of removal, not on the age of the question/answer.

Comment: @Mast https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/157730 *"Reputation changes from bounties, votes (both up and down), and acceptances on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question) are nullified. (Exception: Reputation earned for posts with a score of three or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, is retained)."*

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3):

A few things stand out. First, the ex-mod that locked it, and the ex-mod that answered it. Part of the reason that the ex-mod who locked it is an ex-mod is due to actions like this. If you look hard enough, you'll find hundreds of similar historical-locks that don't quite make sense.

Answer (score 3):

[As suggested in comments](http://meta.serverfault.com/users/9517/hangin-on-in-quiet-desperation), it was locked to prevent it from being bumped to the front page ("active" questions view) when I retagged it.  At least as of when I last had diamond privs, unlocking a question was one of the actions that bumped a question to the front page, so it stayed locked.

No sense in stirring that turd back to the top that I could see, but perhaps the current mods will feel differently.

Comment: It doesn't matter. At -4 or below it would not appear on the front page no matter how many changes are made to it.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not very valuable in its current state. There is however one reason I won't vote to delete it. Deleting the question would also delete the answer.

The answer which was given to that question is a good answer. And that answer would also be applicable to more realistic questions that might come up. So there is a possibility that somebody may search for an answer and find that answer useful.

But it is not the question and answer I would consider to deserve the historical question notice. The scenarios where that notice would be most applicable is good questions with good answers which just happens to be off-topic according to our current standards.

The notice has since then been removed, and I think that is all that needed to be done about that question.